# angular-phonecat tutorial- server not working

Tags: git, node.js, angularjs, command-line

I am working through [this tutorial](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_00) in angular-js. when I run the server, nothing seems to happen, my console looks like this:

[image]

This is in `git bash` but I get the same thing in windows console.
When I go to `http://localhost:8000` it is blank and so is `http://localhost:8000/app/index.html`. No error messages.
When I browse to the app folder using windows explorer, `index.html` is present and has code.

Can anyone see the problem?

Answer (score 0):

To be sure noe of your other installed programs interfere with the [Angular JS Setup requirement](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/#environment-setup), make sure to use, in your CMD where you are following the tutorial, to use:

- a [simplified PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44878018/6309)

  ```
   set PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
   set GH=C:\path\to\git
   set PATH=%GH%\bin;%GH%\usr\bin;%GH%\mingw64\bin;%PATH%
  ```
- a PATH completed with the minimum you need

  ```
   set PATH=%PATH%;C:\path\to\npm
  ```

Then try again to launch your server.